# ZK: Refreshing parent window while closing child window

Tags: zk

I want to implement in ZK to refresh a parent window while closing its child window.

Parent.zul - This has a dropdown and a button (label as add to dropdown) to add value to this drop down. when this button clicked, it should open a child winow with an option to enter text to the dropdown.

child.zul : this has a text box to enter value for the dropdown and a "CLOSE" button. when the close button is clicked, it should close the child window and refresh the dropdown in the parent window.

Thanks in advance for your input.

==========================================================================

Parent: sock.zul

```
<window id="sockWindow" title="New Sock" width="600px" apply="SockController" mode="modal" closable="true">
    <div align="left" style="float: left;" >    
        <button id="btnLookup" label="Manage Lookup" width="150px"/>
    </div>    
</window>
```

sockController.java:
public class SockController extends SelectorComposer  {

```
@Listen("onClick = button#btnLookup")
public void onClickAdd() throws Exception {
    showPopup(new EventListener<Event>() {
        @Override
        public void onEvent(final Event event) throws Exception {
            Object someData = event.getData(); // cast to whatever object you expect to give.   
            //Make your refresh code here.                
        }
    });          

}   

public static void showPopup(final EventListener<Event> eventListener)
    throws InterruptedException {
//you can give more params with the method to add them as arguments.
    Map arguments = new HashMap<String, String>();
    arguments.put("source", "parent.zul");
  //  arguments.put("hid", hwid.toString());
  //  arguments.put("displaymode", displaymode);

    openModal("/managelookup.zul",null, arguments, eventListener);
}

public static void openModal(final String page, final Component parent,
    final Map<String, Object> obMap,
    final EventListener<Event> onCloseListener)
    throws InterruptedException {
    for (final Map.Entry<String, Object> entry : obMap.entrySet()) {
        Executions.getCurrent().setAttribute(entry.getKey(),
            entry.getValue());
    }
    Executions.getCurrent().setAttribute(Composition.PARENT, null);
    final Component createComponents = Executions.createComponents(page,
            parent, obMap);
    Component parent1 = createComponents;
    parent1 = getWindow(parent1);
    if (parent1 instanceof Window) {
        final Window window = (Window) parent1;
        if (onCloseListener != null) {
            //attach the listener so when popup is closed the listener is called.
            window.addEventListener(Events.ON_CLOSE, onCloseListener);
            window.addEventListener(Events.ON_CANCEL, onCloseListener);
        }
        window.doModal();
    }
}
```

}

child : managelookup.zul:

```
        <button id="cancel" label="Close"/>
</window>
```

ManageLookupsController.java:
public ManageLookupsController() throws Exception{

```
@Listen("onClick = button#cancel")
public void onClickCancel() {

    manageLookup.setVisible(false);
    manageLookup.detach();
    Events.postEvent(Events.ON_CLOSE, windowOrSpaceOwner, someData);
}
```

}

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I'll show you here some samples of our application :

In the Parent composer, we open the popup and give an eventlistener for the callback :

```
public void onActionShowPopup () {
    showPopup(new EventListener<Event>() {
            @Override
            public void onEvent(final Event event) throws Exception {
                Object someData = event.getData(); // cast to whatever object you expect to give.   
                //Make your refresh code here.                
            }
        });  
}

public static void showPopup(final EventListener<Event> eventListener)
        throws InterruptedException {
    //you can give more params with the method to add them as arguments.
    final Map<String, Object> args = new HashMap<>();
    args.put("modus", "modal");
    openModal("/WEB-INF/webpages/zk/popup/some_popup.zul",null, args, eventListener);
}

public static void openModal(final String page, final Component parent,
        final Map<String, Object> obMap,
        final EventListener<Event> onCloseListener)
        throws InterruptedException {
    for (final Map.Entry<String, Object> entry : obMap.entrySet()) {
        Executions.getCurrent().setAttribute(entry.getKey(),
                entry.getValue());
    }
    Executions.getCurrent().setAttribute(Composition.PARENT, null);
    final Component createComponents = Executions.createComponents(page,
            parent, obMap);
    Component parent1 = createComponents;
    parent1 = getWindow(parent1);
    if (parent1 instanceof Window) {
        final Window window = (Window) parent1;
        if (onCloseListener != null) {
            //attach the listener so when popup is closed the listener is called.
            window.addEventListener(Events.ON_CLOSE, onCloseListener);
            window.addEventListener(Events.ON_CANCEL, onCloseListener);
        }
        window.doModal();
    }
}

public Component getWindow (Component comp) {
    if (comp != null && !comp instanceof Window) {
        return getWindow(comp.getParent());
    }
    return comp;
}
```

And of course in your popup when you close :

```
 Events.postEvent(Events.ON_CLOSE, windowOrSpaceOwner, someData);
```

I created [a fiddle](http://zkfiddle.org/sample/1kje9rv/1-open-popup-with-callback) with this code and where it's working.
Maybe you can see where you make a mistake?

Hope this could be of help.

Comment: Thanks for the code. I did adjust my code by using your code. Pasted it in the post.  It is still not working. Can you please run it on your end?

Comment: Thanks for you reply. I did update my code based on your comment. It is still not working. Can you please run it on your end? There is a line getWindow(parent1) showing an error message (method not found).

Comment: Yeah sorry, just a methode that take parent component and check if it class window, otherwise again getWindow, until parent is null or window found

Comment: So popup needs to be in a window.

Comment: sorry, i didn't get it. Can you please post me the getWindow() method? Is there anything else you see wrong in the code?

Comment: added the getWindow method.  Try again, and let me know if it works.

Comment: Thanks for posting the method. I got an error on postevent in the child window.  "windowOrSpaceOwner" is not defined. what is it suppose to do? is it java class? Can you please check it again?

Comment: You need to give the window component of your popup. This is normally wired, or if you use mvvm you could use @ContextParam.

Comment: after entering the window component, it works. The entire program is compiled OK. but, when i run it, getting "java.nullpointer" exception on the below line.                                                                                        final Component createComponents = Executions.createComponents(page,
            parent, obMap);  - Is this because parent is null? should need to  pass value to it? Thanks for your help again.

Comment: sock.zul (parent) is itself a modal window and the child window (managelookup.zul) is a popup modal window. I am opening sock.zul from another application as modal window.

Comment: As long sock and child are in same application, no worries. The point is adding the eventlistener to your child window, and when closing post the onclose event of that window. Everything should work as expected then.

Comment: i still couldn't get through the error message java.nullpointer exception in final Component createComponents = Executions.createComponents(page,
            parent, obMap);                                                                                           calling with parameters                                                                       Map arguments = new HashMap<String, String>();
        arguments.put("source", "sock.zul");

        openModal("/managelookup.zul",sockWindow, arguments, eventListener); can you please advise?

Comment: Thanks for creating a fiddle. I have compared my code with your fiddle. It all works now. thanks for your help.

Answer (score 1):

I assume your child window is another window with the modal property, so: If you are using MVVM, You can use a GlobalCommand to "refresh" your parent window.

In your parent window viewModel put a method to refresh your dropdown and put in it the @GlobalCommand tag:

```
@GlobalCommand
public void refreshDropDown(){
    //Your code here
}
```

And in your child window if you have a method to close the window then add the call to that globalCommand:

```
public void closeWindow(){
    //your code to close the window here
    BindUtils.postGlobalCommand(null, null, "refreshDropDown", null);
}
```

Or directly in your child window zul you can call it:

```
<button label="Close window" onClick="@command('close') @global-command('refresh')" />
```

You can find more information about it [here](http://books.zkoss.org/zk-mvvm-book/8.0/data_binding/global_command_binding.html), [here](http://books.zkoss.org/zk-mvvm-book/8.0/viewmodel/commands.html) and [here](http://books.zkoss.org/zk-mvvm-book/8.0/syntax/databindingglobalcommand.html)

Comment: Thanks for your reply. I am not using MVVM. how can i do the same in MVC?